# iOS SQLite search. Speed issues

Tags: sql, objective-c, ios, sqlite, full-text-search

My app currently has search functionality to search books. NOTE: Search operation only searches one book at a time.

The problem is that it gets quite slow as the number of downloaded books increases. Basically there is a field in the "pages" db table that contains the textual content of the book. It is set as an index.

Here is the query i'm using:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        page_num, content
    FROM
        offline_pages
        JOIN offline_chapters ON offline_chapters.uid = offline_pages.offline_chapters_uid
        JOIN offline_books ON offline_books.uid = offline_chapters.offline_books_uid
    WHERE
        offline_books_uid = ?
        AND
        content LIKE '%?%'
    ORDER BY
        page_num
) AS temp
ORDER BY temp.page_num
LIMIT 30
```

Users are still complaining about the search feature as the number of books increases. I'm aware that this query is quite heavy but are there ways to improve it at all?

I was looking into the FTS module of SQLite before as a way to get better results etc. Will FTS improve the speed of the query in any way? Also, I'm only searching one book here but does it affect speed if there is pages belonging to other books in the table also?

OR, is it just a case that searching this amount of content is time consuming?

Thanks in advance for any ideas on this.

--Conor

Comment: A `LIKE '%?%'` will necessitate a search through every record in the table(s), at least a string-compare and record retrieval for each row.  Anything you can do other than this clause would be better - FTS, custom tagging, ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, try removing the unnecessary subquery and the duplicate "ORDER BY" statement.  "LIKE" statements are also VERY time-consuming (and in many cases should be avoided whenever possible unless only dealing with a small character string); see if you can change that condition up so that it doesn't have to check every character sequence in that text field.  You may also be able to add some other conditions to reduce the subset of data the like statement must check against.

Another technique is to do your own indexing of the content. Database indexes on columns are really only good for exact matches, not for character sequence searches.  Therefore, try doing your own indexing in your code by parsing the content as it is being added to the your database and create another table with those common words, phrases, or character sequences.